# word or pdf to hosted HTML5 forms?

Tags: html, forms, pdf, ms-word

Is there a good hosted service out there that allows users to import either word docs or pdf's that can be converted into html5 forms. There are plenty of hosted html5 form builders out there, but I'm not having much luck finding anything that allows for a simple import of these standard formats. I have hundreds of pages to convert into digital forms, and would prefer to not have to rebuild each page from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Crocodoc](https://crocodoc.com/why-crocodoc/) may be what you're looking for.